# Is there a NetQuarry like UI for displaying reporting results for Java/Grails?

Tags: java, grails, reporting

The NetQuarry plaform for .Net has a very slick widget for displaying the results of query in a table. It allows the user to choose which columns are to be displayed as well as filter the results displayed by entering text in text boxes at the top of each column. There are additional features, but these are the high points.

I am looking for a similar UI widget that will plug into my Java/Grails application. There is obviously no magic here, but if it has been written I don't want to write it again. I can use either open source or commercial libraries. A reporting tool like BIRT is overkill I think, but I may be missing an important detail. Is such a widget available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is Cam Woods from NetQuarry.  You are probably already aware, but the NetQuarry platform is built in .Net and can be used to build just about any DB-based business SaaS application.

Since you're Java/Grails-based it's probably no help, but we do sell the platform.  Please feel free to contact us at www.netquarry.com if you'd like to discuss further.

Thanks,

Cam